# Does the command systemctl and service exists on linux only and not mac?

Tags: macos, apache, service, status, systemctl

Hi I'm trying to see the status of my apache services on my Mac. I tried the command

```
sudo service httpd status
```

but command not found

I look up in Google and discover `systemctl` so I try that

```
sudo man systemctl
```

and it shows no manual entry for `systemctl`

I noticed that I didn't see much mac os and only see linux in the websites on Google.

Does the command `systemctl` and `service` exists on linux only and not Mac?

If so, what is the mac version of these command?

Answer (score 169, accepted):

The equivalent to Linux [`systemctl`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html) on macOS would be [`launchctl`](https://ss64.com/mac/launchctl.html). Apache also has its own HTTP Server Control Interface, [`apachectl`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/apachectl.html).

↳ **[OS X Man Pages](https://ss64.com/mac/launchctl.html)**

Comment: here is a sample usage of launchctl with nginx: https://derickbailey.com/2014/12/27/how-to-start-nginx-on-port-80-at-mac-osx-boot-up-log-in/

Comment: thanks @cyrilchampier that article by Derick was short and sweet, and worked nicely

Comment: @cyrilchampier Looks like the link is dead :(