# How do I prevent this process from starting on startup?

Tags: postgresql, macos

I was installing postgres and may have installed it twice. The first installation appears to be spinning up a postgres server with a password I admittedly don't remember.

I used `netstat -vanp tcp | grep 5432` to determine the PID then I used `ps aux | grep 560` to find the program (as seen below)

```
postgres           560   0.0  0.0 408830848   2208   ??  Ss   18Apr22   0:10.26 /Library/PostgreSQL/14/bin/postmaster -D /Library/PostgreSQL/14/data
```

How can I go about preventing this program from starting up automatically?

EDIT: I'm on a M1 mac with Monterey 12.3.1

EDIT2:
I've run `sudo launchctl list | grep post` and was able to find the postgres program under

```
560 0   postgresql-14
```

now I'm looking into how to remove it from launchctl

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove autostart of apache on macosx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065288/how-to-remove-autostart-of-apache-on-macosx)

Comment: It's insightful but maybe because I'm on an m1 mac and Monterey 12.3.1, the interface has changed since then so the instructions don't work (w.r.t System Preferences -> Users doesn't exist and Users & Groups which exists doesn't have postgres under Login Items)

I'm trying out the launchlist commands atm though

Answer (score 0):

You can enable or disable services that run on start up by running systemctl command

```
sudo systemctl disable postgres
```

Comment: I get `sudo: systemctl: command not found`

Comment: Are you using mac or Linux? this command is for Linux
for mac see 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47934081/does-the-command-systemctl-and-service-exists-on-linux-only-and-not-mac
it's the equivalent for it in mac

Comment: I'm on mac. `launchctl` works. I'm looking around for the command to remove postgres though, I'll update the question with the output of `sudo launchctl list`